# How to add = to request body to call rest api

Tags: angular, rest

I've figured out that when calling my API from Angular, the API process inserts a blank row in the database. I made testing with Fiddler and the local API and I was able to insert successfully a row in DB.

I had to add a '=' at the beginning of the JSON (request body) in Fiddler and everything worked as expected.

[FiddlerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvS5L.jpg)

My question would be, how can I add the '=' to the request body from Angular to have this working.

The code from my service.ts

[Service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wtLQ.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your content type. You are sending a JSON string in the request body, but you are identifying the content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". You need to change your Content-Type header value to "application/json".

Do not use the "=" in the request body, as it is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @jjones, I tried changing the content type in Fiddler, it was OK and added a row in DB through API. I changed in Angular as well but now is throwing an error     "{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"customer":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: j. Path '', line 0, position 0."]}}"         I hard-coded a json to test but don't know where the issue is...

Comment: I made a console log for the params variable, this is the result: json={"CompanyName":"First","ContactName":"Second","ContactTitle":"Tres","Address":"Cuatro","Region":"Cinco","PostalCode":"Seis","City":"Siete","Country":"Ocho","Phone":"Nueve","Fax":"Diez","Hired":true,"Active":true}

Comment: "json=" is not valid JSON. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. really appreciated your help.